# I want to learn Jiu Jitsu here in Japan, so do you guys know a school in Japan where they teach Jiu Jitsu, not BJJ?

Tags: jujutsu

I want to learn original Japanese Jiu Jitsu here in Japan, but not BJJ. But I do not know to where to learn. Any ideas?

Comment: Please be aware that you can change your identity, but the question is still off topic. We really do want to help people, but there are guidelines for questions which are there for a reason. Before you ask your next question please take the time to read the Meta post [*How to ask questions on MartialArts.SE*](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/168/70).

Comment: Also make sure you follow the links given in the close reason of your original question - the [Help center stuff](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is very easy to read and really quite helpful.

Comment: "Here in Japan", but in your other question you state you live in China. Which is it?